# Unity activation error occured while trying to get instance of type

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism, unity-container

I am using Prism 4 with Unity Extensions and the MVVM pattern.

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper {
    protected override void InitializeShell() {
        Application.Current.RootVisual = (UIElement) Shell;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
    }
}
```

ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance() throws the following exception :

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Shell,
>   key ""

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in the shell constructor.

If you have parameters in Shell constructor for exemple, dont forget to declare in [ConfigureContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.unityextensions.unitybootstrapper.configurecontainer%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx) of Bootstrapper :

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
...
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
  base.ConfigureContainer();
  this.Container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

**Shell.cs**

```
...
public Shell(IMyService container)
{
    ...
}
```

You can read this doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868(v=pandp.40).aspx

Comment: Shell's constructor isn't executed. ConfigureContainer overriding doesn't help

Comment: Yes if you have Activation error, the Shell's constructor isn't executed. Have you some parameters in Shell's constructor ? See the inner exception for more detail on activation error.

Answer (score 0):

I have two seperate suggestions:

1)ensure that the name property of shell.xaml is not empty

2)If 1 does not help change the InitializeShell like this:

```
 IShellView shell = new Shell();
 shell.ShowView();
 return shell as DependencyObject;
```

I hope these could help.